# Connecting to virtual machine when no connection to internet

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, webserver, airport

I'm having problems connecting to my local virtual machine if I'm off the internet. When I'm properly connected to the internet, I have no problem also connecting to my local server.

## Setup

- Host: MacBook Pro, OSX Snow Leopard
- Guest: VirtualBox, Fedora with Apache Httpd webserver

## Use case

I am developing web applications, which are served by my local virtual webserver.
I browse them from the host browser.

When AirPort is correctly connected to a wifi, I can also connect to the local webserver, but as soon as I don't have wifi connection, or if I turn off AirPort manually, I also lose the connection to the local webserver. This is a problem since I would like to be able to take my laptop anywhere and be able to do development work.

## The solution?

Should I change the network setting for the vm in VirtualBox, or is it a OSX setting related to AirPort or the ethernet card that can fix this?

If you need more details about my configuration, let me know and I will amend.

Thanks,
Jakob

Comment: In the end I found a solution myself, see my answer below. If you have another/better solution, or can explain why this works or won't work in some situations, please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a local wifi network by selecting

```
Create Network
```

from the AirPort dropdown menu (the wifi icon).

In the dialog "Create a Computer-to-Computer network." just go for the defaults.

This will ensure your AirPort adapter doesn't deactivate.

Then configure it with this command in the terminal:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 192.168.0.11 netmask 255.255.254.0 up
```

This will reenable its routing capabilities.

I don't know if the ip addresses might be different in your case, but I think the important thing is the netmask, making sure the ip addresses of host and guest are in the same subnet.

I solved my problem like this, hope others can use this answer.

Comment: How do you know that the correct IP address is 192.168.0.11? Surely this varies by network?

Comment: I'm sure it may vary. I guess you could find a way to get the correct IP address before trying this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell Virtualbox to not use NAT Mode, which depends on ONE certain host-only connection to be activated. Instead, you can use Host Only, which will not care if there is Internet or not. Option two is to use Bridged mode, but through a host only adapter (more work).

In the event this happens often, I would just add a second NIC to the VM, that is Host Only. Use that IP address, even if on the Internet, when you want to connect to the Virtual Machine. It will only be visible to your host anyways, and isn't reliant on anything else.

With NAT mode, you will NEED to be connected to a network with your host in order to use this mode. Same thing with Bridged, except Bridged makes the VM more like a physical machine by having it's own IP address on the network you're connected to

Comment: I have both a NAT adapter and a Bridged adapter, and now I tried to add a Host-only adapter. It didn't help. Are you saying I should only keep the Host-only, and remove the others?

Comment: I would recommend ADDING or replacing NAT with Host Only. When you do, you do not need Internet access at all for the VM to connect, or to connect to the VM

Comment: I tried removing the NAT adapter and restarted the vm. The ip address to the vm is the same. I still cannot connect, but instead of "Can't connect" / "No route to host" I now get put on hold: "Server is taking too long" / "Operation timed out". This even happens while AirPort is on and connected, so it's kind of a step backwards ;-) Thanks for the help so far, hope you have a few more ideas up your sleeve!

Comment: Are you using a static IP on the VM? If so, this won't work

Comment: I'm not sure how the ip is assigned, but I think it's VirtualBox managing it, and it always stays the same. Why should it not be static?

Comment: When switching network types, you should let it be DHCP so you can always get whatever address it needs. If it's in a server that will never change, then static IP is fine